# How To Create Parms Enum[] Overload That Casts To Ints

Tags: c#

Given this LinqPad C# Program

```
void Main() { Test(new [] {(int)Foo.A, (int)Foo.B, (int)Foo.C}); }

// External Library Call
public void Test(IEnumerable values){ values.Dump(); }

public enum Foo { A,B,C }
```

I wanted to simplify the call site for Test, so I created this helper method:

```
public void Test(params Foo[] values){
    Test((IEnumerable)values);
}
```

Which turned the call site into just:

```
Test(Foo.A, Foo.B, Foo.C);
```

But I quickly noticed the output changed from

```
0
1
2
```

to

```
A
B
C
```

How do I keep the `params Foo[]` signature (since it makes the call site extremely clean), but have it treated as `int`, not `Foo`?

*I've added my solution, but I'm interested to see if there is something simple that I missed.*

Comment: Try `.Cast<object>()`

Comment: @SLaks nope.  Still A,B,C

Answer (score 3):

```
public void Test(params Foo[] values)
{
    var valuesAsInts = values.Select(x => (int)x);
    Test(valuesAsInts);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just calling `Cast<int>()` doesn't work, so I created another helper method to convert it to an `object[]`.

```
void Main()
{
    Test(Foo.A, Foo.B, Foo.C);  
}

// External Library Call
public void Test(IEnumerable values){
    values.Dump();
}

public enum Foo {
    A,B,C
}

public void Test(params Foo[] values){
    Test(ToObjectArray(values.Cast<int>()));
}

public static object[] ToObjectArray<T>(IEnumerable<T> values)
{
    var array = values.ToArray();
    var objArray = new object[array.Length];
    array.CopyTo(objArray, 0);
    return objArray;
}
```

The output is now what it should be:

```
0
1
2
```